# RabbitMQ - Basic_qos function and how to maximize it

Tags: python, parallel-processing, rabbitmq, distributed-computing, distributed

I have been using RabbitMQ for building a distributed web crawler. 
So far, I have been using this function so that each only gets 1 request at a time.

```
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
```

For what I understand, no matter how many queues the channel has, it will always process just 1 message at a time.

Is there a way so that I can maximize the number of messages processed at a time? I didn't want to make this `prefetch_count` static but instead to process as many messages as my computer can at a given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a prefetch (qos) then RabbitMQ will send your consumer as many messages as the connection can handle. So just don't call basic_qos at all.

To maximise the throughput of your connection, don't send an ack per message but use the basic_ack with multiple=true, and acknowledge large batches of messages at a time.

This comes with risk. If your connection dies, you'll have a load of messages redelivered and if you batch your acks, you'll reprocess a whole lot of messages too. But if your consumer is a web crawler then the worst that could happen is that it crawls a site or page twice so no big deal.

Comment: it seems like there is a problem with this solution though. It seems like if I don't use the prefetch, messages are completely lost.

For example, I am using 2 queues at the same time and I can notice that messages are lost in 1 of the queues sometimes. With the prefetch this does not happen.

Comment: And I used `ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag, multiple=True)`

Comment: I can't say why that is. Could be a bug in the library you use. From RabbitMQ's perspective, the lack of a prefetch only affects the number of messages it sends you without acknowledgement. You could have a slow connection without a prefetch and have a hundred of so messages in flight/not acknowledged yet, or a super fast connection with a prefetch of 1000 and have reached the 1000 unacknowledged messages. RabbitMQ is reliable in both scenarios.

Comment: For what I noticed now, the messages aren't really lost but they take way longer to be consumed now, since the previous queue is overwhelming the node, that's how I see it.

Comment: That is one of the drawbacks of not using a prefetch. You can get unequal distribution of delivery to different consumers, or in your case unequal distribution of messages to a single consumer from different queues (though I have never been in a situation to see that myself). I think you should look at using a prefetch, and find the sweet spot for your needs. Also consider having a different consumer and channel for each queue. You can host them in the same process.

Comment: Great advice, you are right! Finding the best prefetch_count seems like an option, but how do I do that?
Moreover, I have tried to call the channel method on the connection, `channel = connection.channel()`, for each queue. However, it does not seem to make a difference. Do you really think having 1 consumer per queue will help? I guess the problem is in the consumer itself that is not consuming from the second queue.